# Cannot read property 'getDOM' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm migrating `angular-2.0` app to `angular-4.0`.

**side Note** : *I have added animations library as suggested.*

**systemjs.config.js**

```
 '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // added animations for 4.0 

      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',


      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
```

It is said in [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14733) that we need to add

```
import { ɵgetDOM as getDOM } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

but after adding it, it says,

> Module '"../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'ɵgetDOM'.

**package.json**

```
"@angular/common": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/core": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/http": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/animations": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/router": "~3.3.0",
 ...
```

Comment: Great to see you posting a question. I am also struggling with the same error. Figuring out to fix it

Comment: Been trying to figure it out since last 2 to 3 hours but still no success.

Comment: It's private API. Don't use it. What will you get if write `import * as platform from '@angular/platform-browser';
console.log(platform.ɵgetDOM);`?

Comment: @yurzui same error.

Comment: even in given thread, given plunker reference, console prints undefined.

Comment: Check this http://plnkr.co/edit/VFgpKMdMotn2NQ07xPuD?p=preview

Comment: it works. but don't know how to make it work in my code. To make sure that I work with latest angular version, I'm importing packages from `https://unpkg.com/@angular/...`(cdn) and not from `node_modues folder`. But then I get different error. not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @yurzui If you wish I can give you access to my code.

Comment: @Aravind any update on it?

Comment: @micronyks still working on. :(

Comment: @Aravind check n try with my answer and check it works for you or not and update me for the same.

Comment: No luck. didnt work for me

Comment: what's the problem in your case?

Comment: NoopAnimationsModule issue

Comment: Oh are you using angular2 materia?

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE***: This answer doesn't resolve `Cannot read property 'getDOM' of undefined` error but now I'm at least able to run the app with `Angular4.x` and I have no error while running the app.

I don't know if this is the right answer or not.

But somewhere in **angular2** path/progress a file called `systemjs-angular-loader.js` was introduced and unfortunately it was not there in my project.

So, I added it and performed following steps,

**1)** added [systemjs-angular-loader.js](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/src/systemjs-angular-loader.js) to project.

**2)** updated `app` section in `systemjs.config.js` as follow,

**2.1)**

previously,

```
packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        ...
      },
      ...   
    }
```

Now,

```
packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
       ...
      },
      ...
    }
```

**2.2)**

In my case, somehow the latest version of `router library` (calling from `node_modules folder`) giving me some error.

```
'@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
```

so replaced with **unpkg.com** network (cdn) reference (as of now)

```
'@angular/router': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/router@next/bundles/router.umd.js',
```

Now it has started working.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular 4 + material UI . i have added follwoing to systemjs.config.js, Its working for me .

'@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
'@angular/animations':'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/***animations.umd.min.js',***
      '@angular/animations/browser':'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',

'@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',

Comment: Please highlight what specifically was wrong with the original code and how you changed it to fix it when posting an answer.

Comment: That's great ! But those files or references were already there in the project.

Comment: @angular/animations':'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.min.js',   This line made the trick , I am new to java script , but i am guessing that *.umd.min.js  is present in right format  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error after upgrading to 4.0.0, but mine was with @angular/http.

Turns out that I didn't have @angular/http in my package.json, but I had a copy of the js file existing in my final output directory (http.umd.js).

Because of this, the version of http that was out there was still old. So make sure that you aren't missing one of the required libraries from your package.json.

My first clue was that @angular.http was the wrong version under Dependencies/npm in Visual Studio and had "extraneous" next to it.