# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDOM' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

*PS*: I have checked many posts but couldn't get satisfactory solution. (So if you mark it as a duplicate then please share an answer too)

I am using ionic 2 and it has very basic functionality i.e. to send post request to the server. I am using very simple `import { Http } from '@angular/http';`.

**Code**

```
    var link = 'https://mywebsite.com/myws/Login';
    var data = JSON.stringify({ username: this.username, password: this.password });

    this.http.post(link, data)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }, error => {
        console.log("Oooops!");
    });
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "medical-bot",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.3.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-device"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "MedicalBot: An Ionic project"
}
```

**Error**

When I run on chrome I get following error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDOM' of undefined
    at CookieXSRFStrategy.configureRequest (xhr_backend.js:167)
    at XHRBackend.createConnection (xhr_backend.js:207)
    at httpRequest (http.js:20)
    at Http.request (http.js:120)
    at Http.post (http.js:137)
    at LoginPage.doLogin (login.ts:37)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginPage.html:113)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11892)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13184)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:12772)
```

Comment: where is `getDOM` in your code

Comment: @sachilaranawaka I haven't explicitly call `getDOM`. It might be called `at Http.post (http.js:137)`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305024/cannot-read-property-getdom-of-undefined and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14733